# md-swipe-left and md-swipe-right is doing same functionality (moving only left) on md-tabs in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, swipe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxRa2.png)angular material's md-tabs swiping functionality is not working properly i.e in two ways .It is working fine for left but when i swipe to right , left functionality is firing.

Here. I open site with mobile mode. so the swiping is working well with arrow button click event. but when i swipe on the tabs for left swipe it is working but for right swipe also it is doing same functionality as left swipe

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is caused due to 'pointerevents' API. The 'pointercancel' event is fired when a browser defaults to handling touch events as pan,zoom,etc by itself. The way angular-material handles its touches, a 'pointerdown-pointercancel' event is treated as 'pointerdown-pointerup'. So scrolling down or swiping in any-direction will trigger a 'pointerdown-pointerup' immediately, causing the framework to detect it as a left-swipe.

**Solution 1**

Apply the css rule:

```
md-tabs-content-wrapper, [md-swipe-left], [md-swipe-right]  { touch-action: pan-y; }
```

This will correctly detect the swipe direction.
But you will face another problem. Scrolling up/down will cause the tabs to change !!

**Solution 2**

Do not listen to pointerevents. Mouse and touch events will suffice on desktops and mobiles.

You will have to make changes in angular material code.
If using the angular-material.js file, 
Change the following:

```
// Listen to all events to cover all platforms.
var START_EVENTS = 'mousedown touchstart pointerdown';
var MOVE_EVENTS = 'mousemove touchmove pointermove';
var END_EVENTS = 'mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel pointerup pointercancel';
```

To:

```
// Listen to all events to cover majority of platforms.
var START_EVENTS = 'mousedown touchstar';
var MOVE_EVENTS = 'mousemove touchmoev';
var END_EVENTS = 'mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel';
```

The issue is recognized and still open.
Here's the discussion: 
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10145

Answer (score 0):

Expansion of [Devesh Sati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5135319/devesh-sati)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42620599/8578829):

if you're using angular-material.min.js,

replace

```
var v="mousedown touchstart pointerdown",E="mousemove touchmove pointermove",$="mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel pointerup pointercancel";
```

with

```
var v="mousedown touchstart",E="mousemove touchmove",$="mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel";
```

> just remove pointer events i.e. `pointerdown`, `pointermove`, `pointerup`, `pointercancel`