# Fullcalendar callback on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, event-handling, fullcalendar

I want to add fullcalendar to my project. In general almost everything works as expected. But now I'm facing with an issue that appears only on mobile devices. When I click on some row in a day view, dayClick and select callbacks should be fired. And on desktop they do. But on Android Chrome nothing happens until I change day, month or view type (from day to month). So all this callbacks are fired when new view is rendered.

I've tried to debug. And on the desktop after I click on the timeslot, DragListener.prototype.endInteraction is called with event type 'mouseup'. On the mobile this function is called only when I switch the view. It looks like touch event is recognized as a dragging or scrolling. Only "click" outside of timeslots - for example "next day" button is recognized as touch event.

It's hard to replicate this issue on the jsfiddle. Because even the example from fullcalendar site is working as expected. But maybe this is known problem or someone have had similar issue?

Configuration:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                views: {
                    month: {
                        selectable: false
                    }
                },
                height: 450,
                eventLimit: 4,
                locale: 'pl',
                viewRender: self.viewRender,
                defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                longPressDelay: 1,
                selectLongPressDelay: 1,
                selectable: true,
                header:{
                    left: 'title',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'today prev,next'
                },
                dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {
                    console.log(view.name);
                    if (view.name === "month") {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
                    }
                },
                eventRender: function(event) {
                    console.log('event render:', event);
                },
                eventAfterRender: function(event) {
                    console.log('event after render:', event);
                },
                eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                    console.log('event click:', event, jsEvent, view);
                },

                dragScroll: false,
                droppable: false,//: 1,
                timezone: 'local',
                aspectRatio: 1.6,
                select: function(start, end) {
                    console.log('select clicked:', start, end);
                    console.log('---> day click 2');
                }
            })
    });
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular-joyride": "^1.0.10",
    "angular-material-badge": "^1.2.9",
    "angular-touch": "^1.5.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "intro.js": "^2.9.3",
    "jquery-parallax.js": "^1.5.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery.ui.touch": "0.0.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "save-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.13",
    "angular": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-aria": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-fullpage.js": "^0.2.6",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.10",
    "angular-messages": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-resource": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-route": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-translate": "^2.18.1",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "^2.5.6",
    "angular-ui-calendar": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate": "^0.8.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "font-awesome-sass-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "font-awesome-webpack": "0.0.5-beta.2",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.4.0",
    "fullpage.js": "^2.9.7",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-minify-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.13",
    "ng-template": "^1.0.0",
    "ngtemplate-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.8.0",
    "statuses": "^1.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Angular Material 1.1.10 interfere with fullcalendar. It overrides touch handling in some way. And event is recognized as mousedown instead of touchstart.

Solution is to remove all pointer events from:

```
var START_EVENTS = 'mousedown touchstart pointerdown';
var MOVE_EVENTS = 'mousemove touchmove pointermove';
var END_EVENTS = 'mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel pointerup pointercancel';
```

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/42620599/5940387